# Deleting foreign key value

Tags: python, django

I have got a model that looks like that:

```
  coupon = models.ForeignKey(
        'Coupon', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

When I am trying to delete the coupon using this function:

```
def remove_coupon(request):
    coupon = Order.objects.get(
        user=request.user, ordered=False)
    coupon.coupon.delete()
    return redirect("core:checkout")
```

It deletes the coupon from `Order` model, but it also deletes the coupon in the `Coupon` model. I wanted to make it so it only deletes the value from `Order` and not from `Coupon` model.

I have also tried `on_delete=models.CASCADE` , but my site crashes then. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the foreign key to `None`

```
def remove_coupon(request):
    order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    order.coupon = None
    order.save()
    return redirect("core:checkout")
```

You can also do this is a single query

```
Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False).update(coupon=None)
```